# PC1 and PC2 values: original values

Tags: pca

I just ran PC analysis in r on the iris data set. This has been discussed several times in the past but I am little confused on the output. 
    I used prcomp and this is output for the loadings:

```
                    PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971
```

Here is the first 6 rows for the scores:

```
           PC1        PC2         PC3          PC4
[1,] -2.257141 -0.4784238  0.12727962  0.024087508
[2,] -2.074013  0.6718827  0.23382552  0.102662845
[3,] -2.356335  0.3407664 -0.04405390  0.028282305
[4,] -2.291707  0.5953999 -0.09098530 -0.065735340
[5,] -2.381863 -0.6446757 -0.01568565 -0.035802870
[6,] -2.068701 -1.4842053 -0.02687825  0.006586116
```

Here is the first 6 rows for the original values:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Could someone explain how we get the PC1 score of -2.25 for row 1?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation (`?prcomp`), the PC scores are the data — centred and scaled, if requested — multiplied by the rotation matrix. So, let's do that calculation for row 1 and PC 1 to check. In this example, I use a PCA object imaginatively called `pca`.

First, we centre the first row of data, `iris[1, 1:4]`, using `pca$center` and then scale using `pca$scale`. Finally, we multiply by the loadings for PC 1, `pca$rotation[, 1]`, and sum the result.

```r
# Perform PCA
pca <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

# Calculate PC1 score for first row of 'iris'
sum(pca$rotation[,1] * (iris[1, 1:4] - pca$center) / pca$scale)
#> [1] -2.257141
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

As expected, we get -2.257141.